# Custom tableview in appcelerator titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, tableview, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm working on a `tableView` application in Titanium. In which I need to display data in two sections.
In **section 1** I want to display the cell seperator and in **section 2** I don't want any cell seperator.

I can use seperator style propery of tableview to remove the seperator style like:

```
separatorStyle: Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewSeparatorStyle.NONE,
```

But my issue is it'll remove cell seperator from entire tableView. But I don't want that, I need seperator in Section 1.

The tableView is something like:

[image: TableView]

**Is this possible to achieve ? or I need to customize the second section with a single Row and add separate labels to it ?**

Comment: @RajeevNB: can you please share some thoughts about how this can be done.

Comment: I prefer you seeing the sample code of Kitchen Sink here https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Titanium Appcelerator's TableViewRow documentation (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-property-selectionStyle) you don't have the property **separatorStyle**, because it is a property of TableView.

Try make make manually your rows separator (in first section):

```
    tableViewRow.add( Ti.UI.createView({
            height: 1,
            width: Ti.UI.FILL,
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
            bottom: 0
    }) );
```